# Unable to create Maven project in Eclipse through proxy

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy, project

When trying to create a Maven project with archetype in Eclipse, I'm getting this error:

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.   
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): unexpected end of stream on Connection{repo.maven.apache.org:443, proxy=HTTP @ /XXXXXXXXXX:XXXX hostAddress=XXXXXXXXXX cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.   
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): unexpected end of stream on Connection{repo.maven.apache.org:443, proxy=HTTP @ /XXXXXXXXXXXX hostAddress=XXXXXXXX cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
```

I've tried proxy settings in Maven setting.xml. I setup network connections for http, https for Eclipse. I'm unable to download plugins in the Eclipse Marketplace.

Logs:

```
Contains: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): unexpected end of stream on Connection{repo.maven.apache.org:443, proxy=HTTP @ /XXXXXXX:8080 hostAddress=XXXXXXcipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): unexpected end of stream on Connection{repo.maven.apache.org:443, proxy=HTTP @ /XXXXXX:8080 hostAddress=XXXXXXXcipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$5.call(MavenImpl.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$5.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.resolveArchetype(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:870)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProjects0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:784)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$5.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$5.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizard$5.doCreateMavenProjects(MavenProjectWizard.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstractCreateMavenProjectJob$1.doCreateMavenProjects(AbstractCreateMavenProjectJob.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.run(AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstractCreateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(AbstractCreateMavenProjectJob.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Talk to the admin that is responsible for the proxy. Maybe access to MavenCentral is generally blocked.

Comment: firstly thanks for your response. ok I will check with admin but I am able to download plugins via eclipse marketplace. the only problem i am facing now is with maven.

Comment: A proxy or firewall is not a yes no thing. It is possible that the firewall allows you download one file, but not the other. It can even depend on the program you use (something works in the browser, but Eclipse cannot access it).